# Парсинг модального окна на php

Tags: php, phpquery

Мне необходимо спарсить информацию, которая подгружается в модальное окно, при его открытии, адрес страницы при открытии модалки не меняется. Подгружается она на js. Для парсинга использую phpQuery. То есть просто прописать путь к нужному тегу не получится, потому что парсер не найдёт данных из модалки. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: посмотреть исходный код страницы. найти код модалки и проверить есть ли в нем нужные данные. Если есть - использовать. Если нет - посмотреть аякс запросы при открытии этого окна. продублировать их напрямую, и получить данные.

Comment: не подскажите, как можно продублировать аякс запрос?

Comment: а как вы страницу эту запрашиваете чтобы в phpquery данные закинуть? вот вместо этого возьмите и получите данные по той ссылке, которая аяксам запрашивается. с теми же параметрами и при необходимости специфичными заголовками запроса